# How to manually send download request to an application

Tags: networking, download, internet-connection, netstat

I'm downloading a file from telegram desktop app. I want to see if it's possible that I can find a download link and use a tool like `lftp` to download the file myself with multiple tcp connections if supported by the server.
so I did a netstat and grepped tcp. And then used whois to find out the according application and I could find `91.108.4.136` and `149.154.164.224` as `Telegram Messenger Network` but I can't find how the exact root to my file. How can I do that!? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 by the way. I also have wireshark if it helps.

Comment: You would have to actually capture the connection and requests. As Telegram is most likely using some form of encryption for the connection (TLS/SSL at least?) you might not be able to do this in an easy setup.

Comment: all the keys must be in my local computer somewhere so that shouldn't be an issue:-? @Seth

Comment: While that is true it actually can be as they might e.g. just be in memory and you might not be able to just read them. But as you already have all the tools just give it a try? Fire up wireshark, capture traffic and look at whenever you can read the Telegram traffic or not. Write a message yourself and see whenever it shows up in the traffic you're seeing in a readable manner.

Comment: You may use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).